# Kotlin generics: How to pass an instance of interface T<A,B> to T<Any, Any> where A and B are both in/out?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I would like to use an interface with parametrized types, in a way that does not really care about the types.

In Java, I would achieve that by using `? extends Object`. But I can't figure out how to do that in Kotlin with it's `in`/`out` concept.

I have an interface:

```
interface EntityAdapter<BusinessType: Any, DatabaseType: Any> {
    fun adaptFromDbEntity(dbEntity: DatabaseType): BusinessType
    fun adaptToDbEntity(businessEntity: BusinessType): DatabaseType
}
```

Then a function which does not really care about the types (shortened) :

```
fun verifyReadability(entityClass: Class<*>, adapter: EntityAdapter<Any, Any>?): ReadabilityResult {
    ...
    val businessEntity = adapter.adaptFromDbEntity(dbEntity)
    val dbEntity2 = adapter.adaptToDbEntity(businessEntity)
    ...
}
```

The problem is that:

1. I can't pass an adapter to the function like this:

   ```
   val adapter: EntityAdapter<Transaction, DynamoDBTransaction> = ...

   verifyReadability(DynamoDBTransaction::class.java, this)
   ```

   Because the cast to `EntityAdapter<Any, Any>` fails with `ClassCastException`.

   > class DynamoDBTransactionRepository cannot be cast to class EntityAdapter
2. I can't apply `in` or `out` to `EntityAdapter` as both params are `in` and `out`.
3. I can't use `EntityAdapter<*, *>` because then internally, the types are evaluated as `Nothing`.

How should I code this?

I suspect that the problem is that what is actually used as adapter is a `companion object`:

```
class DynamoDBTransactionRepository {
   companion object : EntityAdapter<Transaction, DynamoDBTransaction>{
   ...

      verifyReadability(DynamoDBTransaction::class.java, this)
}
```

Before making the `companion object` implement the interface, it was `this@Companion`, but after that, the compiler can't take that.

---

Edit:
I have tried to wrap the calls like this:

```
object Adapter : EntityAdapter<Any, Any>{
    override fun adaptFromDbEntity(dbEntity: Any) = DynamoDBTransactionRepository.adaptFromDbEntity(dbEntity as DynamoDBTransaction) as Any

    override fun adaptToDbEntity(businessEntity: Any) = DynamoDBTransactionRepository.adaptToDbEntity(businessEntity as Transaction) as Any
}
```

And it works fine, but doesn't seem right. I would prefer to figure out the generics properly, without casting.

---

Edit 2:
I have looked at the [Type projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-projections), but I think I can't apply that since my function calls both "reading" and "writing" methods of the interface `EntityAdapter`:

```
fun verifyReadability(entityClass: Class<*>, adapter: EntityAdapter<Any, Any>?): ReadabilityResult {
```

Comment: Could `verifyReadability` just take `adapter: EntityAdapter<*, *>?`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to have strongly typed type parameters, but you don't actually care what they are, you could simply make the function itself generic:

```kotlin
fun <A: Any, B: Any> verifyReadability(entityClass: Class<*>, adapter: EntityAdapter<A, B>?): ReadabilityResult {
    ....
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work: when caling `adapter.adaptFromDbEntity(dbEntity)`, the compiler expects `B`, but I have only `Any` for it.        I think that my need is not "the function to have stronly typed  parameters", but rather to use the same function with various implementations of an interface, and working with the objects that the interface "reads" and "writes".

Comment: Actually it may be a good direction. I got further by changing `entityClass: Class<DbEntity>`, which also is one of the `EntityAdapter`'s types.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do a fundamentally type-unsafe thing in a typesafe way.

If you as a developer can guarantee that what you write is correct, even if the compiler cannot prove it, you could simply cast the parameter to `adaptFromDbEntity` to `B` and suppress the warning about it being an unsafe operation.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint from @BambooleanLogic, I changed the function to look like this:

```
fun <BusinessEntityT: Any, DbEntity: Any> verifyReadability(
    entityClass: Class<DbEntity>, 
    adapter: EntityAdapter<BusinessEntityT, DbEntity>?
): ReadabilityResult { ... }
```

(instead of `Class<*>`).

With the `entityClass` typed, the Java API used (DynamoDBClient) returned `DbEntity` instead of `Any`, and that is later passed to the interface, so the types clicked and I had no more need to treat it as `EntityAdapter<Any, Any>` with casts.

I hope this excercise will help someone to avoid using `*` where not appropriate.